# Slow link. Seeing this DSL statistics - is it rather me or my ISP?

Tags: isp, adsl, dsl, adsl-router, fritzbox

My typical DSL speed used to be about 9Mbit/s down and 1Mbit/s up, just as advertised. Yesterday it dropped below 0.2Mbit/s (measured with modem's WLAN turned off and my laptop as a single wired device connected to the modem).

Does the data below provide any clue if the problem is likely to be on my or rather ISP's side of the outlet?

[image: link established]
[image: spectrum]
[image: connection properties]
[image: modem's log]
[image: ping 8.8.8.8]
[image: speed test]

Comment: Why exactly did you disable the WLAN?

Comment: It looks to me like this is not a DSL related problem - I don't know we can say any more with the information provided.

Comment: Great to hear you got it sorted. Please note that Super User has a Q/A format. Don't add the solution to your question, add an answer. Don't forget to "accept" your own answer after 48 hours!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The contract was supposed to be a flat rate. However, a data volume limit was mistakenly assigned, beyond which the throughput was throttled.

It only took three weeks, five technicians and a replacement modem delivered and sent back to get this sorted. Funnily, I used the wording "as if my link is throttled" in every communication. Guess what happens when they try to book the flat rate option. The wrong one gets booked. Guess what happens when correcting this. Contract's minimum duration re-starts, too.